# There Isn’t Enough Memory Available to Create a Ramdisk Device, Error Code 0xc0000017

Tags: windows, windows-10, installation

I'm trying to reinstall Windows 10 via USB, but I'm receiving `There Isn’t Enough Memory Available to Create a Ramdisk Device, Error Code 0xc0000017` error

I tried:

- Decrease shared memory on BIOS to 64 MB (minimum)

  Find memory badblocks with `bcdedit /deletevalue {badmemory} Badmemorylist` (no badblocks was found)

  Boot normally and use the "Restore" function (Take 9 hours and got
  stuck in 39%)

  Update BIOS

  Increase Windows Pagefile

It's a notebook with 2GB RAM and already has Windows 10 installed. I search on internet and i'm not found any effective solution to solve it. What should I do?

Comment: Did the computer come with a recovery partition or image, or did you check if one is downloadable from the manufacturer? Windows won't install into 2GB RAM any more, so you'll need a special build from the manufacturer.

Answer (score 2):

I was booting with USB created with Ventoy. Just created with Rufus with GPT option and Windows booted correctly

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else comes by this for answers, i ran into this issue while trying to run Hirens PE from USB.
Apparently, booting in legacy can cause this to,l happen if the OS you're trying to load was designed for UEIF boot.
I don't know enough to be able to tell,you why this is the case, but i hope it helps someone in the future.